# View to Controller communication in MVC

Tags: python, model-view-controller

I am implementing a GUI application in Python and i'd like to use the MVC pattern. I am struggling to understand how the MVC fully works, so i developed a small GUI application to try to understand it better, i will then extend concepts to my real app.

The app is very simple, please see attached figure. First row contains a text-space and a button "write", i will here enter some text in the text-space and by pressing the button it will write that line in a excel file. 
Second row has a similar configuration but by pressing the "read" button, it will read a cell from Excel and display it into the text box. The app is quite straighforward, it needs to highlight the viewer-to-model control and vice-versa. 
Here is the pic:

[MVC app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjogz.png)

Here is the code:

view.py

```
import wx


class view(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "mvc")

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        box_h = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.txt.SetFocus()
        self.txt.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnEnter)
        box_h.Add(self.txt, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL, 5)


        self.btn_write = wx.Button(panel,-1,"Write")
        self.btn_write.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onWrite)
        box_h.Add(self.btn_write,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        box.Add(box_h,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        box_h_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.btn_read = wx.Button(panel,-1,"Read")
        self.btn_read.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onRead)
        box_h_2.Add(self.btn_read,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        self.text_display = wx.StaticText(panel, label="", style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.text_display.SetBackgroundColour((255,255,255)) # set text back color
        box_h_2.Add(self.text_display,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        box.Add(box_h_2,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)
        panel.SetSizer(box)


##########################################################

    def OnEnter(self, event):
        text = self.txt.GetValue()
        print text

    def onWrite(self, event):
        print "onWrite"

    def onRead(self, event):
        print "onRead"

##########################################################



# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = view()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

model.py

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

class model():

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = ""
        self.book = ""
        self.sheet_index= ""
        self.sheet = ""

    def setPath(self,path):
        self.path = path

    def setWorkSheetIndex(self, index):
        self.sheet_index = index

    def loadBookandSheet(self):
        self.book = load_workbook(self.path)
        self.sheet = self.book.worksheets[0]

    def write(self, string):
        self.sheet.cell(2,1).value = string
        self.book.save(self.path)

    def read(self):
        return self.sheet.cell(1,1).value
```

So far so good. The model can read and write to a file excel and the view class displays the GUI, tested them separately on CML and it all works. 
Next is the controller class, as i read around, it needs to have instances of both view and model so that it can handle the comunication between them, while implementing the whole logic of the program. For instance, the user would press the "read" button on the GUI, the GUI passes this info to the controller, the controller calls the "read" method of the model and then the controller updates the display of the GUI.

controller.py

```
from view import view
from model import model
import wx


class controller():

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, view, model, app):
        self.view = view
        self.controller = model
        self.app = app

        self.view.Show()
        self.app.MainLoop()

    def setPath(self,path):
        self.path = path


    def setWorkSheetIndex(self, index):
        self.sheet_index = index



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = view()
    model_ = model()

    controller_ = controller(frame, model_, app)
```

Here is my problem. Since "controller" contains "model", i can easily communicate between them. "Controller" also contains "view" so once i have the data from the model, i could implement a method in the controller class that updates the display in the GUI.

But, how can i communicate from the view to the controller? How can i implement the "user presses the read button and the controller calls the read method of the model?" I do not see any way the information could go from the GUI to the controller class using events.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, i hope it'll help other people. This said, as far as i understood, MVC can be implemented in several ways, so probably this won't be the more effective but it works. I made the view -> controller communication using a publisher-subscriber to send events and data. Controller -> model communication is very simple, was made by simply calling the methods and finally, the model updates the state of the view again with publisher->subscriber. Following the code. Please keep in mind that when entering the user input you need to press enter in order for the text to be accepted. There are for sure better solution but that was not my purpose. Following the code:

view.py

```
import wx
from pubsub import pub



class view(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):


        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "mvc")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        box_h = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.txt.SetFocus()
        self.txt.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnEnter)
        box_h.Add(self.txt, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL, 5)


        self.btn_write = wx.Button(panel,-1,"Write")
        self.btn_write.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onWrite)
        box_h.Add(self.btn_write,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        box.Add(box_h,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        box_h_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.btn_read = wx.Button(panel,-1,"Read")
        self.btn_read.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onRead)
        box_h_2.Add(self.btn_read,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        self.text_display = wx.StaticText(panel, label="", style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.text_display.SetBackgroundColour((255,255,255)) # set text back color
        box_h_2.Add(self.text_display,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        box.Add(box_h_2,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)
        panel.SetSizer(box)
        self.text = ""
        pub.subscribe(self.updateDisplay, 'display_channel')


##########################################################
    def updateDisplay(self, value):
        self.text_display.SetLabel(str(value))

    def OnEnter(self, event):
        self.text = self.txt.GetValue()

    def onWrite(self, event):
        pub.sendMessage("write_channel", write=self.text)

    def onRead(self, event):
        pub.sendMessage("read_channel", readValue=1)

##########################################################



# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = view()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

model.py

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pubsub import pub


class model():

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = ""
        self.book = ""
        self.sheet_index= ""
        self.sheet = ""


    def setWorkSheetIndex(self, index):
        self.sheet_index = index

    def loadBookandSheet(self):
        self.book = load_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
        self.sheet = self.book.worksheets[0]

    def write(self, string_text):
        print "string " + string_text
        self.sheet.cell(2,1).value = string_text
        self.book.save("myfile.xlsx")

    def read(self):
        value_ = self.sheet.cell(1,1).value
        pub.sendMessage("display_channel", value = value_)
```

controller.py

```
from view import view
from model import model
import wx

from pubsub import pub as pub

print('pubsub API version', pub.VERSION_API)

# notification
from pubsub.utils.notification import useNotifyByWriteFile
import sys

useNotifyByWriteFile(sys.stdout)

class controller():

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, view, model, app):
        self.view = view
        self.model = model
        self.app = app
        self.money = ""

        pub.subscribe(self.writeChannel, 'write_channel')
        pub.subscribe(self.readChannel, 'read_channel')

        self.view.Show()
        self.app.MainLoop()

    def readChannel(self, readValue):
        self.model.loadBookandSheet()
        self.model.read()

    def writeChannel(self, write):
        print write
        self.model.loadBookandSheet()
        self.model.write(write)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = view()
    model_ = model()

    controller_ = controller(frame, model_, app)
```